# Expresssion is of wrong type when calling function using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to call *FND_CONCURRENT.WAIT_FOR_REQUEST* from the PL/SQL API for Concurrent Processing using python and cx_Oracle. In order to call *WAIT_FOR_REQUEST* the following parameters need to be provided
:

```
(         request_id IN number default NULL,
          interval   IN number default 60,
          max_wait   IN number default 0,
          phase      OUT varchar2,
          status     OUT varchar2,
          dev_phase  OUT varchar2,
          dev_status OUT varchar2,
          message    OUT varchar2) return  boolean;
```

So my python code looks like:

```
submitted_request = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
phase = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
status = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
dev_phase = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
dev_status = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
message = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
cursor.callfunc('fnd_concurrent.wait_for_request', submitted_request,
                [141116467,
                 1,
                 1,
                 phase,
                 status,
                 dev_phase,
                 dev_status,
                 message])
```

But when I try to run the code the following error appears:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

My insights are that `submitted_request` is causing the problem but I cannot find in the documentation how to get a boolean from a function (I've already tried `int` but no luck so far).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this answer to a similar question - I was also going to suggest an anonymous block wrapper to return a valid SQL type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217140/cx-oracle-get-boolean-return-value

Comment: It worked, thanks @kfinity

Comment: Is this a homework question?  It was also asked (and answered) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379599/how-to-correctly-call-fnd-concurrent-wait-for-request-stored-function-via-cx-ora/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following kfinity's suggestion about using [an anonymous block wrapper](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html#pl-sql-stored-procedures) and a [pretty similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217140/cx-oracle-get-boolean-return-value), the following code is going to work:

```
outVal = cursor.var(int)
phase = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
status = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
dev_phase = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
dev_status = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
message = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
sql="""
  begin
    :outVal := sys.diutil.bool_to_int(
        fnd_concurrent.wait_for_request(
            :id,
            :interval, 
            :max_wait,
            :phase,
            :status,
            :dev_phase,
            :dev_status,
            :message
        )
    );
  end;
  """
cursor.execute( 
    sql,
    outVal=outVal,
    id='141116467',
    interval='1',
    max_wait='1',
    phase=phase,
    status=status,
    dev_phase=dev_phase,
    dev_status=dev_status,
    message=message
)
print(outVal.getvalue())
```

Comment: In any not-even-so-recent version of cx_Oracle and the Oracle Client, there's no need to map  the boolean, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68386070/4799035

Comment: I'm using cx_Oracle v 8.2.1. And bool conversion is a solution for me. What is version where conversion is not required?

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean directly as follows:

```py
phase = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
status = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
dev_phase = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
dev_status = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
message = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
submitted_request = cursor.callfunc('fnd_concurrent.wait_for_request', bool,
                [141116467,
                 1,
                 1,
                 phase,
                 status,
                 dev_phase,
                 dev_status,
                 message])
```

Note that `cursor.callfunc()` will internally create a variable of the type specified as the return type (`bool` in this case) and then return the value of that variable as the return value of `cursor.callfunc()`.